# Find images being referenced in WP8 app

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

How to find which images are being actually used/referenced from all the included images in the windows phone 8 silverlight application in visual studio. Is there any fast way rather than manually deleting a single image and checking for errors each time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support in VS for detecting reference/unreferneced images/resources. The only way I can think of using 'Find in Files' option. By finding the image name one by one in all the files of the solution and see if this image is used anywhere or not.